# Why this Jpa Query is not working when i use count inside query it is not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

**please help i have placed hidden inside package and import something else is there please mind the change **

```
package hidden;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import hidden;

public interface SubscriberIdDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<SubscriberIdDetails, Integer> {

    @Query("Select count(distinct s.msisdn) from subscriber_details s where s.subscriber_details_id in (select d.subscriber_details_id from subscriber_id_details d where d.UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(id_number,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']', ''))=:idNumber")
    Integer countByidNumber( @Param("idNumber") String idNumber);
}
```

Comment: Your query is calling `REGEXP_REPLACE`, which is a database-specific string function.  It won't run as pure JPQL, so you will have to pass `native=true` to the end of `@Query` to mark it as a native query.

Comment: Thankyou so much its working now....!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is calling `REGEXP_REPLACE`, which is a database-specific string function. It won't run as pure JPQL, so you will have to pass `nativeQuery=true` to the end of @Query to mark it as a native query.

```java
public interface SubscriberIdDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<SubscriberIdDetails, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.msisdn) FROM subscriber_details s WHERE s.subscriber_details_id IN (SELECT d.subscriber_details_id FROM subscriber_id_details d WHERE d.UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(id_number,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']', '')) = :idNumber",
           nativeQuery = true
    )
    Integer countByidNumber(@Param("idNumber") String idNumber);
}
```